# Why read the id register in __turn_mmu_on?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

After a few of days reading code about the ARM linux kernel booting process, I understood most of them except several tricky parts in function `__turn_mmu_on:`

```
        .align  5
   __turn_mmu_on:
      mov   r0, r0
      mcr   p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0       @ write control reg
      mrc   p15, 0, r3, c0, c0, 0       @ read id reg
      mov   r3, r3
      mov   r3, r3
      mov   pc, r13
   ENDPROC(__turn_mmu_on)
```

The last instruction `mov pc, r13` will branch to `__mmap_switched`, as follows:

```
    __mmap_switched:
        adr r3, __switch_data + 4
        ....
```

- Why it is necessary to align it at 32 byte (which is the size of a cache line) boundary?
- What's the purpose of reading the value of ID register (whose value is not even used), since register `r3` is simply overwritten in instruction `adr r3, __switch_data + 4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alignment is *probably* not required, but is likely used to ensure that the whole function fits into a cache line and so the last few instructions will be executed from the cache and won't have to be fetched from the memory (even though the function *should* remain at the same address with MMU on because it's identity mapped).

It was not easy to track down the origin of the `MRC` instruction but I *think* I [found it](http://archive.arm.linux.org.uk/lurker/message/20040404.023530.ea36cc49.en.html):

```
Date: 2004-04-04 04:35 +200
To: linux-arm-patches
Subject: [Linux-arm-patches] 1204.1: XSCALE processor stalls when enabling MMU
--- kernel-source-2.5.21-rmk/arch/arm/kernel/head.S    Sun Jun  9 07:26:29 2002
+++ kernel-2.5.21-was/arch/arm/kernel/head.S    Fri Jul 12 20:41:42 2002
@@ -118,9 +118,7 @@ __turn_mmu_on:
     orr    r0, r0, #2            @ ...........A.
 #endif
     mcr    p15, 0, r0, c1, c0
-    mov    r0, r0
-    mov    r0, r0
-    mov    r0, r0
+    cpwait    r10
     mov    pc, lr
[...]
+/*
+ * cpwait - wait for coprocessor operation to finish
+ * this is the canonical way to wait for cp updates
+ * on PXA2x0 as proposed by Intel
+ */
+    .macro    cpwait reg
+    mrc    p15, 0, \reg, c2, c0, 0    @ arbitrary cp reg read
+    mov    r0, r0                    @ nop
+    sub    pc, pc, #4                @ nop
+    .endm
```

The ensuing discussion on merits of this patch [ended in the current approach](http://archive.arm.linux.org.uk/lurker/message/20040404.024034.bbb1b1e4.en.html):

> ...
>   We can however get closer to the Xscale recommended sequence by
>   knowing how  things work on other CPUs, and knowing what we're doing
>   here. If we insert  the following instruction after the mcr, then this
>   should solve your issue.
>
> ```
> mrc p15, 0, r0, c1, c0
> ```
>
> Since the read-back of the same register is *guaranteed* by the ARM 
>   architecture manual to return the value that was written there (if it 
>   doesn't, the CPU isn't an ARM compliant implementation), this means we
>   can guarantee that the write to the register has taken effect. The use
>   of the "mov r0, r0" instructions are the same as in the CPWAIT macro. 
>   The mov pc, lr is equivalent to the "sub pc, pc, #4" (they are defined
>   to be the same *class* of instructions), so merely adding one
>   instruction  should guarantee that the Xscale works as expected.
>   ...

The original patch was from Lothar Wassmann, the final code is probably by Russel King.

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for the link :-)